# How to generate a caller graph for function call directly on singlton instance?

Tags: doxygen

I have been trying to generate some caller graphs for some visualizations. But I ran into a little problem that doxygen doesn't recognize the following line as a function call for the the caller graph.

```
SingltonClass::Instance()->Init(this);
```

The following works fine but his kind-of code is used all over the place in the project so I was wondering if there is a option I need to set to get it to recognize the functions.

```
SingltonClass* single= SingltonClass::Instance();
single->Init(this);
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? can you give a little bit a bigger example that shows the problem and that can be run directly )including the changes you made to your doxygen configuration file)?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.18 on windows. For a bigger example i have so make something up because rather  big project. I use the extract_all, CALL_GRAPH, CALLER_GRAPH and HAVE_DOT the rest is al default for now.